# how to change scrollbar position in dataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I set `FrozenColumnCount=‘2’`,HorizontalScrollBar will show after the last Frozen column,but i want the scrollbar show normally.

The Code:

```
public class MyDataGrid:DataGrid
    {
        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
        {
            var scrollBar = VisualTreeHelpers.GetChildObject(this, "PART_HorizontalScrollBar") as ScrollBar;
            var parentGrid = VisualTreeHelpers.FindVisualParentOfType<Grid>(scrollBar); 
            var size = base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeBounds);
            
            scrollBar.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0,0),new Size(parentGrid.RenderSize.Width,scrollBar.DesiredSize.Height)));
            return size;
        }
    }
```

The xaml:

```
<local:MyDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding List}" Loaded="FrameworkElement_OnLoaded" >
        <DataGrid.FrozenColumnCount>2</DataGrid.FrozenColumnCount>
       <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="col1"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="col2"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="col3"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="col4"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="col5"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="col6"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
   </local:MyDataGrid>
```

I try to call `scrollBar.InvalidateArrange()`,but it also doesn't work.
When i resize window,the scrollbar will show as expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the layout of a control you generally have to override the default `ControlTemplate`. In this case you must explicitly tell the horizontal scrollbar to span across two columns of the hosting `Grid` (the frozen column and the non-frozen column).

The following tweak is based on the default `Style` for the `DataGrid` found on [Microsoft Docs: DataGrid ControlTemplate Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/datagrid-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#datagrid-controltemplate-example).
The `Style` should be similar to the Style you get when using Blend or Visual Studio to extract the default control `Style`.

The `ControlTemplate` contains a `ScrollViewer`. The template of this `ScrollViewer` is modified in order to exclude the frozen columns.
To accomplish this, the horizontal `ScrollBar` is added to a `Grid` that defines two columns: the first acts as a placeholder for the frozen columns and the second to host the `ScrollBar`.
To implement your desired layout, simply allow the scroll bar to span across both columns:

```xml
<ScrollViewer.Template>
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      ...


      <Grid Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Allow the ScrollBar to span across both columns to include the frozen columns -->
        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                   Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                   Orientation="Horizontal"
                   ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                   Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                   Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                   Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </ControlTemplate>
</ScrollViewer.Template>
```